# LGPO.exe don't work when export directory contains spaces

Tags: windows, cmd, executable

LGPO.exe can't export local policy to a GPO backup when in export path is space for example:

```
LGPO.exe /b C:\Users\MYPC 1234\Downloads\LGPO\LGPO_30
```

When i enter command above LGPO returns this error:

```
Invalid directory name for GPO backup: C:\Users\MYPC
```

So I think that LGPO.exe thinks that space means next comand(in this case `/n`) and I don't know how to tell LGPO that that is a path.

Thanks for support

Comment: `LGPO.exe /b "C:\Users\MYPC 1234\Downloads\LGPO\LGPO_30"`?

Comment: Hello thanks all comments are rights. It works using 'LGPO.exe /b "C:\Users\MYPC 1234\Downloads\LGPO\LGPO_30"'

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for stupid question. I was asking this because i wanted to run LGPO.exe from c# and I wasn't able to run it with arguments as above. So best answer is:
`LGPO.exe /b "C:\Users\MYPC 1234\Downloads\LGPO\LGPO_30"`

BTW in c# is this what i was searching for but i didn't asked

```
    Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = "\"C:\\Users\\MYPC 1234\\Downloads\\LGPO\\LGPO_30\\LGPO.exe\""; // LGPO.exe path
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "/b \"C:\\Users\\MYPC 1234\\Downloads\\LGPO\\LGPO_30\\abc\"";
p.Start();`
```

thanks